# How to put the actual model (referenced in a foreign key) in the json representation of the referencing model (Django)

Tags: json, django, django-models

I have this Employee model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )

    MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('S', 'Single'),
        ('M', 'Married'),
    )

    id = models.IntegerField(default=20230000, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(default="mail@gmail.com")
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='M')
    maritalStatus = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True)
    availableVacationDays = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    approvedVacationDays = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    birthDay = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Employee: {self.name}"
```

and
this Vacation model:

```
class Vacation(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('P', 'Pending'),
        ('A', 'Approved'),
        ('R', 'Rejected'),
    )
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vacation')
    startDate = models.DateField()
    endDate = models.DateField()
    vacationReason = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='P')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.employee} wants to take a vacation from {self.startDate} to {self.endDate}."
```

When I send the vacations through a `JsonResponse`,

```
def get_vacations(request):
    vacations = Vacation.objects.all()
    vacation_list = serializers.serialize('json', vacations)
    return JsonResponse({"vacations": vacation_list})
```

I get only the employee_id instead of the actual object. How can I include the actual Employee object in the json sent in `JsonResponse`?

I tried this, but it did not work

```
def json(self):
        return {
            "employee": self.employee,
            "startDate": self.startDate,
            "endDate": self.endDate,
            "vacationReason": self.vacationReason,
            "status": self.status,
            "hello": "hello"
        }
```

It just replaced the key name of `employee_id` with `employee`.

Comment: Use a `ModeLSerializer` (this ships with the Django-REST-framework): https://django-rest-framework.org